# RavenDB and XUnit: Multiple Tests per TestClass

Tags: c#, integration-testing, ravendb, xunit

I currently try to setup some integration testing in order to verify that my RavenDB queries return what i expect.

I followed the [documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/start/test-driver#complete-example) and have a single test up and running.

The problem starts when i add an additional test method to the same class. I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot configure server after it was started. Please call 'ConfigureServer' method before any 'GetDocumentStore' is called.
```

So basically it tells me, the server is already running. But this confuses me. Since XUnit creates an new instance of the test class for every discovered test method in that class. Additionally it calls `Dispose()` on any instance, that implements `IDisposable`. Which is indirectly implemented by the base class `RavenTestDriver`.

So what i think is happening:

1. XUnit creates a new instance of my test class
2. XUnit calls my test method
3. My test method calls `ConfigureServer`, the RavenDB Embedded Server is started
4. My test method finishes
5. XUnit calls `Dispose` on my instance of the test class, the RavenDB Embedded Server is stopped
6. Rince and repeat for the next test method

But i looks like, my assumption on #5 is wrong. The RavenDB Embedded Server seems to be never stopped. Additionally i cannot find a way to manually stop it. I was trying to manually dispoose it with `EmbeddedServer.Instance.Dispose()`. But that doesn't change anything. (The `.Instance` gives a clue, that the EmbeddedServer is probably a singleton, which may be part of the problem here).

I also tried to move the `ConfigureServer` call into the constructor of the test class. Since XUnit class the constructore for every test method (just like the `setup`-method from JUnit). But then i get the same result.

But the interesting part is: Calling `ConfigureServer` in two different classes just works fine.

I have created a small [reproducer repository](https://github.com/ghandmann/RavenDBIntegrationTestingReproducer).

So has anybody an idea on how to setup RavenDB in a Unit/Integration-Test environment where you want to run multiple tests against it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ConfigureServer` method from all tests & constructor. Calling `GetDocumentStore()` will create the embedded server.

https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/e8f08f191e1b085421ca5b4db191b199e7a8fc69/src/Raven.TestDriver/RavenTestDriver.cs#L272

If you want to configure the server then you should set it in a static constructor:

```
        static MovieTests_ConfigureInConstructor()
        {
            ConfigureServer(new TestServerOptions() {
                CommandLineArgs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { "--RunInMemory=true", },
                FrameworkVersion = null,
            });
        }
```

Comment: But how would i then configure the server? Like telling it to run in `inMemory` mode? Or override the .net Core `FrameworkVersion`?

Comment: Ok, but that defeats the purpose of constructors in the XUnit-Framework. Since static constructors are only calle donce. But XUnit has the concept of calling the constructor for each Fact in the Class in order to provide a "Setup"-Method. So i come to the conclusion: The conecepts of XUnit and RavenDB-TestServer don't play nicely with each other?